Dark/Light theme rendering issue Blazor .NET8
I'm trying to add a class 'dark' if it is in localstorage, and remove it if there is 'light' as 'mode' in localstorage.
However, I have the feeling that all pages of my blazor .NET8 application are cached. It saves the mode in local storage, but when I switch pages it doesn't execute the javascript 'onload' statement. Only if I then manually refresh the page again.
I'm curious, does Blazor cache all the pages, because it doesn't re-render the page when you go to it. Does this have to do with a specific rendermode in Blazor?
What I've tried is using the 'onload' param in the body tag. However the onload statement is'nt executed when rendering the page.
<body onload="localStorage.getItem('mode') === 'dark' ? document.querySelector('body').classList.add('dark') : document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('dark')">
I've tried using OnAfterRednerAsync but it applies the styling after it's being rendered. The result you'll get is that the screen show lightmode for a quick millisecond and then applies the 'dark' class to the body tag.

Id make use of IJSRuntime in blazor and then make a call from when home page  component or similar is rendered:
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
 if (firstRender)
 {
     await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("jsmethodToExecute");
 }
 }

find more here: JSRuntime
